# From subdomain to query string, htaccess code

Tags: php, .htaccess

If I enter the following link in the browser.

http://sub.domain.com then it will open http:/domain.com/page.php?c=sub and in the browser address bar visitors will see http://sub.domain.com.

I know it can be done by rewrite url. Can anyone please tell me the htaccess codes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Quite contrary, it **cannot** be done by rewriting url.
You need to set up

- DNS server (to direct all subdomains to your server)
- and web-server (to accept them).

Yet you don't need no query string **nor rewriting**, as you can always easily have your domain from `HTTP_HOST` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I write http://sub.domain.com in the address bar, it's showing page cannot be displayed, bcoz the subdomain is not an existing subdomain. I cannot user HTTP_HOST to get the URL and extract the word "sub".

Comment: As stated above the server has to be configured to listen on the subdomains too.  Assuming DNS is resolving to the correct IP you'll have to setup each individual subdomain to map to the same directory or if you have access to the server config, you can put in a wildcard record for the domain.  Just to clarify a bit... Once all that is in place, THEN you can use the URL rewriting to change sub.domain.com to sub.domain.com/page.php?c=sub if you wish, but at that point you might as well use the HTTP_HOST variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should do it in two steps.

**step 1**:

If you have direct access to your control panel, you should go in it and create a general virtual subdomain using asterisk *

After this step you can use `sub.domain.com`. if you don't have acees to control panel, ask admin to do it for you.

**step 2**:
You should edit .htaccess file with below line

**# Extract the subdomain part of domain.com**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
```

**# Check that the subdomain part is not www and ftp and mail**

```
RewriteCond %1 !^(www|ftp|mail)$ [NC]
```

**# Redirect all requests to a php script passing as argument the subdomain**

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/page.php?c=%1 [R,L]
```

I hope, this helps you